# VBA macro for counting hours on multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have a problem with this macro that refuses to work at all.
I am trying to have the macro sum up the number of classroom hours for Language courses, in order to have a check on long record files.
TO give you a full explanation, on column 2 there is the name of the course (e.g. Advanced English 2) and on column 3 one has the edition (it's a number). The file is previously sorted by column 2, then 3. If the course name and edition is the same it means that I need hours to be added to the total. 
The "Teacher" if refers to the fact that in that column there is either Teacher or Assistant, but the latter don't need their hours counted (so I want to skip the rows where there is one).
The cells in column 5 and 6 are times (e.g. 13:00, 08:45).
I want the code to write in column 12 the number of hours (no matter the format, I know that excel reads dates and times as numbers so I can be happy with just a number in that cell).
Thanks everybody who will be willing to give advice on what I have got wrong :)

ENGLISH;ENGLISH UPPER INTERMEDIATE;30;15/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

ENGLISH;ENGLISH UPPER INTERMEDIATE;30;15/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

ENGLISH;ENGLISH GRAMMAR;36;14/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

ENGLISH;ENGLISH GRAMMAR;36;14/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

ITALIAN;ITALIANO BASE;7;15/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;BR240

ITALIAN;ITALIANO BASE;7;15/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;BR240

ITALIAN;LETTERATURA E STORIA;8;16/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;BR240

ITALIAN;LETTERATURA E STORIA;8;16/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;BR240

ITALIAN;ITALIANO PER IDIOTI;7;21/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

ITALIAN;ITALIANO PER IDIOTI;7;21/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

SPANISH;LA TAUROMAQUIA;17;14/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;LA TAUROMAQUIA;17;14/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH ADVANCED;19;21/01/2014;10:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6012

SPANISH;SPANISH ADVANCED;19;21/01/2014;14:00;17:30;Teacher;A342;U6012

SPANISH;SPANISH 123;17;16/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH 123;17;16/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH ALLEGORIES;18;22/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH ALLEGORIES;18;22/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH LOANWORDS;17;15/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH LOANWORDS;17;15/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;U6014

SPANISH;SPANISH AND PORTUGUESE : WHY?;15;23/01/2014;10:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;U6017

SPANISH;SPANISH AND PORTUGUESE : WHY?;15;23/01/2014;14:00;17:30;Teacher;A342;U6017

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;07/01/2014;08:30;13:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;07/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;07/01/2014;14:00;17:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;07/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;08/01/2014;08:30;13:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;08/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;08/01/2014;14:00;17:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;08/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;09/01/2014;08:30;13:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;09/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;09/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;09/01/2014;14:00;17:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;10/01/2014;08:30;13:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;10/01/2014;08:30;13:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;10/01/2014;14:00;17:00;Teacher;A342;C0329

FRENCH;FRENCH INTENSIVE;48;10/01/2014;14:00;17:00;CoDocente;00348170101;C0691

this is a csv that is similar to my real data :)

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim hoursA As Integer
Dim hoursB As Integer
Dim hours As Integer

z = 3
i = 2
k = 12

Do
hours = 0
Do
t = 1
If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(z, 2) Then
    If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(z, 3) Then
        If Cells(i, 5) = "Teacher" Then
            hoursA = Cells(i, 5).Value
            hoursB = Cells(i, 6).Value
            hours = hoursB - hoursA + hours
            Cells(i, k).Value = hours
        End If
    Else
        t = 0
    End If
Else
    t = 0
End If
i = i + 1
z = i + 1

Loop While t > 0

Loop While UCase(Cells(i, 2)) <> ""


 End Sub
```

Comment: This will be more amazing if you have a sample data-set to work on, including your expectations/expected results. :)

Comment: I can't give the real one to you because it's protected info, but I can modify one for sure :)
I work for a language company and I create macros to simplify my own work
just a sec and I will post it

Comment: ok, done :) 
hope it's better this way

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with the code.

1. Times are stored as fractions, but you're trying to store them in `Integer`s.  Change the three `Hours` variables to type `Double`.
2. Teacher is on column D, but you're checking `Cells(i,5)`.  Change that to `Cells(i,4)`